# How To Set Row As Null After Meeting A Certain Criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to have "Cumulative Customers" be `NULL` after the first 5 "Cumulative Customers":

```
SUM(Customer) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY date DESC) cumulative_customers
```

[image: Ilustration]

The final output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: You write `Set Row As Null` but demonstrate the *column* being NULL, not the whole row. You write `after the first 5 "Cumulative Customers"`, but demonstrate *after the first row with "Cumulative Customers" = 5*. Which is it? And *never* post data as images. Formatted text, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cumulative_customers < 5
              OR cumulative_customers = 5 AND customer >= 1
            THEN cumulative_customers END AS cumulative_customers
     , ... -- more columns
FROM (
   SELECT ...  -- your current query here
   ) sub;
```

If the `ELSE` part is missing it defaults to NULL. You can spell that out, too, if you prefer.

I use `customer >= 1` just in case there can be values greater than 1 (unlike your demo suggests).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a subquery, you can do this using `case`:

```
select (case when SUM(Customer) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY date DESC) <= 5
             then SUM(Customer) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY date DESC)
        end) as cumulative_customers
```

Erwin's solution also works if you want a subquery or CTE.

Comment: The simple condition would return values for all rows with `cumulative_customers = 5`, not just the one with `customer >= 1` (automatically the "first one") like demonstrated in the desired output.